# Share a calculated field column from a Document Set to the documents inside the Document Set

Tags: content-type, document, share

I have created a Document Set content type. That content type has a column of the type calculated field. I can share all other columns I have created, but not columns of the type calculated field. Is that according to plan, a bug or just med doing it wrong?

The formula is looking like this:

```
="C-AG-"&YEAR(Created)&"-"&MONTH(Created)&"-"&DAY(Created)&"-"&HOUR(Created)&MINUTE(Created)&SECOND(Created)
```

And results in something like this:

```
C-AG-2016-1-13-13134
```

This method is used due to historical reasons, so it can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate the Calculated Column in other ContentTypes.

It is a nuisance, not a bug

Just image all the possible things that could go wrong if a DocumentSet ContentType could 'stamp' its Calculated Formula on all ContentTypes used in the Document Set.

- Columns with same DisplayName but different content
- Non-existing Columns

Comment: I don't quite understand... My calculated filed in the DocSet is combining data from other fields (such as Created for example) and creating a unique ID (used for historic reasons...). I would like that ID to be set as metadata for each document uploaded in the DocSet. How can I do that since calculated fields can not be shared from DocSet to doc?

Comment: Show us your Formula (paste it in your question), When you say '*creating a unique ID*' all SharePoint alarm bells go off.